# evaluating limits of piecewise discontinuous functions in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I'm trying to learn sympy through a coursera course and I've set up the following Piecewise function to learn about limits.

The piecewise function I'm trying to express in `sympy` is as follows (apologies, I don't know if or how to make latex render on stackoverflow):

```
    f(x) = {  x^3      x < 3
              2        x = 3
              -(x^2)   x > 3
```

In python I've set it up as:

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.abc import x
from sympy.plotting import plot

# some whacky discontinuous function
fx = Piecewise((x**3, x < 3), (-1 * (x)**2, x > 3), (2, True))
plot(fx, ylim = (-30, 30))
```

which yields the following graph

[image]

I am then trying to evaluate the limits of `fx` and expecting the one sided limits to be `-9` and `27` from the right and left respectively, and `does not exist` for the overall limit.

However when I execute

```
print(fx.limit(x, 3, '+'))
print(fx.limit(x, 3, '-'))
print(fx.limit(x, 3))
```

Each line prints `2` as the answer.

Can someone help identify where I've gone wrong?

Comment: If you try `fx = Piecewise((x**3, x < 3), (2, x == 3), (-1 * (x)**2, True))`, each line will print -9

Comment: This is a bug: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/23836

Answer (score 0):

It worked if
`fx = Piecewise((x**3, x < 3), (-1 * (x)**2, x > 3), (2, x == 3))`

Comment: I don't think that is actually accounting for `f(x) = 2` at `x = 3`. if you evaluate the function at 3 you get `nan`. `print(fx.subs(x, 3)) => nan`

Comment: This answer is wrong, because when you write the condition `x == 3` Python intercepts it and automatically evaluate it to False, hence it doesn't add that piece to the overall function. Remember, you need to use the `Eq` (alias of `Equality`) class: `..., (2, Eq(x, 3))`.